# Распознавание речи в c#

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи

Существуют ли на данный момент какие либо технологии позволяющие распознавать речь на win 7 rus?

Знаю о существовании `System.Speech.Recognition`, но это на сколько мне известно на русской win работать не желает.

Находил инфу о существовании `Microsoft.Speech`,  но тут не сложилось ее даже толком найти, вроде бы все установил, но найти в Reference не удалось (Вернее что-то нашел но подключался `SpeechLib`, который тоже не изъявлял особого желания работать.

Comment: В фирме используются онлайн-сервисы Гугла и Яндекса.

Comment: А в компании используется SRS ;-)